# browser textbox autocomplete event, when does this happen?

Tags: jquery, dom, autocomplete

If i **dont** put `autocomplete="off"` on my `<input type="text" />`s the browser will sometimes fill them in with likely/remembered data.

When does this happen in the DOM-load-lifecycle?

It appears to be after:

```
$(function(){ alert('i happen before autocomplete'); });
```

Is there a dom-load event which occurs after form-autocompletion?

If so, what is it?

If not, meh, what can I do to execute some JS "on page load", but after autocompletion?

Solutions needs to be cross browser

Thanks

Andrew

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could give  `$(window).load(callback)` a try.   This will wait until everything is fully loaded (images etc), rather than just after the DOM has been loaded the way `$(document).ready` does.

I'm not 100% sure whether or not it happens before auto complete but it definitely occurs after DOM ready.

Alternatively you might try registering a "one-off" change event handler when the DOM is ready like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').one('click', function() { 
        // do whatever you wanted to do when it first changed
    });
});
```

This will fire only the first time the field changes.   The only question is whether or not the browser will fire the change event when it does the autocompletion.

Comment: This works perfectly in every case except when you hit `Back` in Chrome. For this, i had to add a 100ms delay inside my window load function. Otherwise, fine :)